# Horizontal line on open and high of candlestick in stockchart

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts

When I hover on any candle I want a horizontal line in green at open and red at close in Highcharts using stockchart. You can play around with the working example where the above functionality needs to be added.

> https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>


Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlc.json', function (data) {

    // create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [
                    [
                        'week', // unit name
                        [1] // allowed multiples
                    ], [
                        'month',
                        [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @vishal, Have you solved your problem yet?

Comment: It's not complete. I want two line on both open and close. The curret solution randomly puts on one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crosshair always indicates a `close` value. If you want to also show a line on a `open` value, you can use the plugin below:

```
(function(H) {
    function removeCustomCrosshair(axis) {
        if (axis.customCross) {
            axis.customCross.remove();
        }
    }

    H.addEvent(H.Axis, 'afterDrawCrosshair', function(event) {
        var point = event.point,
            translateY;

        if (this.customCross) {
            removeCustomCrosshair(this);
        }

        if (this.coll === 'yAxis' && this.cross) {
            this.customCross = this.cross.element.cloneNode(true);
            this.gridGroup.element.appendChild(this.customCross);

            translateY = point.plotOpen - point.plotClose;

            this.customCross.setAttributeNS(
                null, "transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + translateY + ")"
            );
        }
    });

    H.addEvent(H.Axis, 'afterHideCrosshair', function(event) {
        removeCustomCrosshair(this);
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9dz53p2b/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: It is not giving the label of one horizontal line but is giving for other. how can I get labels for both, meaning price for both

Comment: Hi @vishal, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tjxvadho/

Answer (score 0):

Adding this at series level will give horizontal line for one of the high or low price.

```
yAxis: {
  crosshair: {
    label: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```